# Lint errors after migration to AndroidX:

Tags: android-studio, lint, androidx

After migration/refactor to AndroidX (using the migration tool in Android Studio 3.2 RC2), I get a huge set of the following type of Lint errors:

```
participant_menu.xml:9: Error: Should use android:showAsAction when not using the appcompat library [AppCompatResource]
          app:showAsAction="never" />
```

I'm confused; I guess this is an error in Lint related to the migration to AndroidX. Am I correct, or should I switch back to the android namespace?

Note: my minSDK is set to API 16.

Answer (score 0):

> Should use android:showAsAction *when not using the appcompat library*
>   [AppCompatResource]
>             app:showAsAction="never"

If you are not using `Appcompat` library, I believe you should use:

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

([As documentation says](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource))

Also, it seems like there are still some issues in Androidx which needs a documentation or a direct guide for that since I've seen some people had problems with this or with the `SearchView` or etc.